# Ubuntu File System Partition gone Unallocated

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, gparted, data-recovery

I decided to install Windows 7 next to my Ubuntu setup and started to follow this [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu). Currently i'm on the third step. But when i try to mount the file system that i noted down, it says "mount: special device /dev/sda6/ does not exist". Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE2Rf.png) of the current partitions. Since the instructions says that i need to note down the partition name, can i assume that i can still get back what was on my Ubuntu file system?

Is it possible to make unallocated partition in the image, functional again? Did my whole Ubuntu installation got wiped out? Should i try using testdisk to get back the unallocated partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you (or a bug) have accidentally deleted your Ubuntu partition. To get it back, I recommend using [TestDisk.](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) This isn't 100% guaranteed to work, but there's a good chance it will. The odds of success go *way* down if you created that NTFS partition in a location that used to hold the Linux partition. If that's the case, your best bet of any sort of recovery is to use [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to recover individual files. That will be tedious, and there's a good chance that some files will be completely lost.

Whatever you do, write ***nothing*** to that disk until you've recovered it! Note that booting a modern OS invariably writes files to its boot partition, and sometimes elsewhere, so this means you should ***not*** boot Windows! Do your recovery from an Ubuntu (or some other OS's) live CD.